# Call a script when a windows service is stopped intentionally

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, windows-server-2012-r2

Is there a way to call a batch or Powershell script when a windows service is stopped intentionally from Services(services.msc), I have a couple of tasks that need to be performed when my Application service stops. I have a script which checks for the status of the service that could call another script if the Windows Service is not running, but that works with a time schedule so if stop and start the service immediately the script wont execute as the Service would be in running status by then.

Comment: At the risk of sounding stupid, any reason why you don't build the signaling mechanism into the application service itself? It is by far in the best position to hear about it. Failing that, you can create a scheduled task that triggers on the event written to the log by the Service Control Manager when you ask a service to stop, but be aware that that could still run and do things while the service is already up and running again -- the only way to avoid that is to have the service take care of things itself.

Comment: The application is a proprietary, so it cant be changed. I have another Application service which is like an add-on the the application. I want my add-on application to be stopped when I stop the service.

Comment: Polling still sounds like your best shot in this case. Track the start time of the service process to detect if the service has restarted in between polls. Note that you *cannot* ensure that your application is stopped before the service restarts; that would require the ability to block the service start entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute an infinite loop that polls for the service.

```
While ($True)
{
    If (-not (Get-Service -Name 'myproc')) { <# do a thing #> }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

(I don't have enough rep to do this as a comment, so I'm leaving an "answer" - sorry in advance!)

There's no way that I know of to start a script on an event like a stopped service.  You can use the "Stop-Service" cmdlet with Powershell in conjunction with your current service monitoring script in order to keep the service from restarting while you're running your script, then have a "Start-Service" at the end to allow it to come back up.